# scala case class with CircularFifoQueue

Tags: scala, scala-generics

Scala compiler throws compilation error for the following

```
case class UserSession(userEvents: CircularFifoQueue<UserEvent>)
```

Following error messages are from Scala REPL:

```
$scala -cp Downloads/commons-collections4-4.1.jar 
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue;
import org.apache.commons.collections4.queue.CircularFifoQueue

scala> case class UserSession(userEvents: CircularFifoQueue<UserEvent>)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but ')' found.
case class UserSession(userEvents: CircularFifoQueue<UserEvent>)
                                                               ^

scala> case class UserSession(userEvents: CircularFifoQueue<int>)
<console>:1: error: identifier expected but ')' found.
case class UserSession(userEvents: CircularFifoQueue<int>)
```

Comment: Have you first use your preferred search engine and/or read Scala tutorials/docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[]` for generics in scala not diamonds (`<>`) which is java thing.

so should be `case class UserSession(userEvents: CircularFifoQueue[UserEvent])`

simple generics example,

```
scala> class Bag[T]
defined trait Bag

scala> case class Apple()
defined class Apple

scala> new Bag[Apple]()
res4: Bag[Apple] = Bag@1ef93e01
```

### resources

http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/113